# SQLite CREATE TABLE syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create SQLite database like this :

```
private static final String UID = "_id";
private static final String NAME = "Name";
private static final String TYPE = "Type";
private static final String UNITS = "Units";
private static final String CURRENCY = "Currency";
private static final String PRICE = "Price";
private static final String ADD = "Default";
private static final String WEATHER = "Depends";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
     " CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
     " ( "  +UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
     NAME+     " VARCHAR (255), "+
     TYPE+     " VARCHAR (255), "+
     UNITS+    " VARCHAR (255), "+
     CURRENCY+ " VARCHAR (255), "+
     PRICE+    " VARCHAR (255), "+
     ADD+      " VARCHAR (255), "+
     WEATHER+  " VARCHAR (255)  ); ";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

getting this error log:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Default": 
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Meters ( _id INTEGER 
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR (255), Type VARCHAR (255), Units 
VARCHAR (255), Currency VARCHAR (255), Price VARCHAR (255), Default VARCHAR 
(255), Depends VARCHAR (255)  );
```

I really don't see a problem :-/ any advice what could be wrong are welcome, thanks guys

Comment: May be its because of ADD, change to add to some other name like ADDS or etc.

Comment: I suppose DEFAULT(case insensitive) is a  keyword and can't be used as a row name. Just a guess. Try another name instead of Default.

Comment: More like "Default" is the problem, which is the value of ADD, change _that_ to something else.

Comment: DEFAULT or ADD, non of them can be in name, not the variable. So my String ADD = ... is ok, but when I had there String = "add" there was also problem obviously. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is a keyword in SQL. Change your column name in the variable `ADD` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `ADD` it cannot be `Default` as that is a reserved word in SQL

Answer (score 0):

`Default` is SQLite's keyword. You probably shouldn't use it as a name. If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it.

Here are some SQLite docs you might want to check: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html